# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "escalo" y "butrón"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, sinónimos

Ayer aprendí una palabra nueva: [***escalo***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G7EqtPN). Me la encontré en este contexto:

> Lo cierto es que ningún periodista tiene derecho a cometer delitos para obtener información por muy relevante que esta sea. ¿Se imaginan? **Robo con escalo** para obtener unos papeles de casa de Zoido, un robo de móvil por tirón para conseguir saber qué habla Soraya con Rajoy o cualquier otra versión.
>
> <sub>Elisa Beni - [*Es un escándalo*](http://www.eldiario.es/zonacritica/escandalo_6_735336488.html)</sub>

La frase *robo con escalo* necesita de explicación. Mirando el DLE vemos qué es tal palabra:

> 1. m. Acción de escalar<sup>1</sup>.
>
> 2. m. **Trabajo de zapa o boquete practicado para salir de un lugar cerrado o penetrar en él.**

Claramente la acepción que aquí aplica es la segunda, la de hacer un agujero para acceder a una casa y robar. Sin embargo, leyéndola me vino inmediatamente a la cabeza la palabra que conocía con este sentido:

> [**butrón**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6MOw0xc)
>
> 1. m. **Agujero hecho en suelos, techos o paredes para robar.**
>
> 2. m. buitrón (‖ arte de pesca).
>
> 3. m. vulg. Ál. Agujero o chimenea que sirve para la ventilación de cuevas abiertas bajo tierra donde se guarda el vino.

Y aquí es donde me surge la duda: ¿en qué se diferencian ambas palabras? Busqué un poco y me encontré con muchos falsos positivos, pues *escalo* normalmente aparece en su primera acepción (que es sinónima de [*escalada*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G6GuLRJ)), o puramente como forma conjugada de *escalar*.

Comment: El robo con escalo en jerga legal creo que es más bien escalando o accediendo al lugar por zonas no usuales (balcones, ventanas, alcantarillas...)

Comment: @blonfu bien visto. Una de las primeras entradas me lleva a [un documento de información policial](https://pacoleon.wikispaces.com/file/view/Manual+sobre+ROBOS.pdf) que dice: _entrar por un lugar no desinado al efecto (no natural, insólita o desacostumbrada) siempre que ello exija una destreza o esfuerzo de alguna importancia para trepar o ascender a un determinado lugar_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya se ha adelantado en los comentarios, en la noticia a la que haces referencia la palabra *escalo* se usa con su primera acepción: "acción de escalar". Podemos verlo en noticias como [la siguiente](http://www.diariodehuelva.es/2018/01/12/dos-detenidos-robo-escalo-dos-viviendas-san-juan/) (elimino el resaltado de la noticia original y hago el mío propio):

> La Guardia Civil y la Policía Local de San Juan del Puerto procedieron a la detención de dos varones [...] por un supuesto delito **robo con escalo** producidos en dos viviendas de la localidad. [...] Las investigaciones llevaron a la identificación de dos jóvenes que [...] **subían a un balcón trasero** de una de las viviendas y seguidamente **saltaban hacia uno de los patios** para acceder al interior.

Es decir, se usa *robo con escalo* para indicar que se ha accedido al lugar del robo trepando o colándose por algún lugar poco habitual o no destinado a tal efecto. Sin embargo, sí es cierto que la palabra *escalo* tiene una según acepción que, efectivamente, recuerda a la de la palabra *butrón*.

Lamentablemente, no encuentro en el CORDE ningún caso que me haga pensar en esa acepción. Lo curioso es que en el diccionario esa segunda acepción fue en realidad la primera que apareció en el diccionario. En 1184 el DLE definía la palabra así:

> Trabajo de zapa ó taladro practicado para evadirse de un lugar cerrado ó penetrar en él ocultamente y con dañado propósito.

Y añade que viene de la segunda acepción de *escalar*, que por entonces era:

> Abrir rompiendo alguna pared, tejado, etc.

Y ponía como ejemplo "escalar la cárcel". Resulta llamativo rastrear el significado del verbo *escalar*, ya que en 1732 el de Autoridades definía la palabra así:

> Poner escálas à una casa, muralla ò pared para entrar dentro.

Es decir, se usaba en el contexto del asalto a una ciudad, como en el ejemplo que pone: "Los Soldados de Scipión pretendieron por allí *escalar* la Ciudád". De hecho este sentido sigue siendo la primera acepción de *[escalar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G6T25Xg)* hoy día (y la de "abrir una pared" es la cuarta), aunque en realidad la acepción más usada sea la sinónima de "trepar".

Vemos pues que la palabra "escalo" también tuvo en su día el significado de "entrar abriendo agujeros con propósitos dañinos". El problema es el ya comentado: que la palabra "escalar" se usa hoy como "trepar", y por tanto un "robo con escalo" se entiende como un "robo con escalada". El uso de *escalo* para denominar a a acción de robar mediante el uso de agujeros en estructuras fue sustituido por el uso de *butrón*, que entra en el diccionario en 1983 como "agujero que los ladrones hacen en techos o paredes para robar", indicándose que es una palabra procedente de la germanía.